# Validar formato de fecha con jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un input de tipo date pero al correrlo en el safari puedo editarlo de cualquier forma y quiero validar que se escriba de la forma correcta con jquery?

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaentrega" name="fechaentrega">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿en el formato mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Cuando hablas de forma correcta, a que haces referencia?

Comment: a la forma del tipo type="date" del input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aquí te dejo la validación con jquery. Esta para cuando pierda el foco el *input*  valide la  fecha. Lo que hace es enviarte un Alert que te dice si es invalida o es correcta en caso que sea correcta teda la fecha completa.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaentrega" name="fechaentrega" value="">

$("#fechaentrega").focusout(function(){
  s= $(this).val();
  var bits = s.split('/');
  var d = new Date(bits[2] + '/' + bits[0] + '/' + bits[1]);
  alert(d);
});
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que se está pasando en el orden correcto (d/M/y)? ¿y dónde se está realizando la validación?

Answer (score 0):

Para validar en el formato dd/mm/yyyy:

```js
function isValidDate(dateString)
{
    // revisar el patrón
    if(!/^\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}$/.test(dateString))
        return false;

    // convertir los numeros a enteros
    var parts = dateString.split("/");
    var day = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
    var month = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
    var year = parseInt(parts[0], 10);

    // Revisar los rangos de año y mes
    if( (year < 1000) || (year > 3000) || (month == 0) || (month > 12) )
        return false;

    var monthLength = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ];

    // Ajustar para los años bisiestos
    if(year % 400 == 0 || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0))
        monthLength[1] = 29;

    // Revisar el rango del dia
    return day > 0 && day <= monthLength[month - 1];
};


$("button").click(function() {
alert( isValidDate($("#fechaentrega").val()) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="date" class="form-control" id="fechaentrega" name="fechaentrega" value="2012-12-15">
<button>send</button>
```

Referencia original [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6178341/4987172)

Solo recuerda que `date` no es compatible en el navegador `firefox`. Considera utilizar alguna librería como [moment js](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

268

La expresión regular que pegó no valida los años bisiestos correctamente, pero hay uno que sí lo hace [en la misma publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates/8768241#8768241) . Lo modifiqué para llevar `dd/mm/yyyy`, `dd-mm-yyyy` o `dd.mm.yyyy`.

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

Lo probé un poco en el enlace que Arun proporcionó en su respuesta y también [aquí](https://regexr.com/346hf) y parece funcionar.

Edite el 14 de febrero de 2019: eliminé una coma que estaba en la expresión regular que permitía fechas como `29-0,-11`

tomado de otra respuesta en la sección de ingles y traducido al español, para ver original [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score -1):

Usando `jQuery` y validar fecchas en formato `DD/MM/YYYY` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Validar la fecha **a medida que es ingresada**

```js
$('.input-date').on('input', function (evt) { 
  var v = this.value,
      l = v.length,
      d,
      b;
  if (
    l === 1 && /^[0-3]/.test(v) || // D
    l === 2 && /^0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]$/.test(v) || // DD
    l === 3 && /^\/$/.test(v[2]) || // DD/
    l === 4 && /^[0-1]$/.test(v[3]) || // DD/M
    l === 5 && /^0[1-9]|1[0-2]$/.test(v[3]+''+v[4]) || // DD/MM
    l === 6 && /^\/$/.test(v[5]) || // DD/MM/
    l === 7 && /^[12]$/.test(v[6]) || // DD/MM/Y
    l === 8 && /^\d$/.test(v[7]) || // DD/MM/YY
    l === 9 && /^\d$/.test(v[8]) || // DD/MM/YYY
    l === 10 && /^\d$/.test(v[9]) // DD/MM/YYYY
  ) {
    
    // Control fecha valida
    d = v.split(/\//);
    if (l === 10) {
      b = (new Date(d[2], d[1] - 1, d[0])).toISOString().substr(0,10).split('-')
    }
    
    // Meses con 3* dias
    if (l === 5 && v[0] === '3' &&
      (d[1] === '02' ||
       (v[1] === '1' && ['04','06','09','11'].indexOf(d[1]) !== -1)
    )) {
      ;//Error, el mes no tiene 3* dias
    }
    // Año bisiesto
    else if (l === 10 && d[0] === '29' && d[1] === '02' && b[2] != d[0]) {
      ;//Error, el año no es bisiesto, febrero no puede tener 29 dias
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  this.value = v.substr(0, l - 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-date" />
```

- Validar la fecha ingresada al hacer `blur` del `input`

```js
function isValidDate (value) {
  var valid = false,
      info,
      real;
  
  // Validar formato
  if (/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/]\d{4}$/.test(value)) {
    
    // Validar fecha
    info = value.split(/\//);
    real = (new Date(info[2], info[1] - 1, info[0])).toISOString().substr(0,10).split('-');
    if (info[0] === real[2] && info[1] === real[1] && info[2] === real[0]) {
      valid = true;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

$('.input-date').on('focusout', function(){
  console.log(isValidDate(this.value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-date" maxlength="10" />
```

- Validar la fecha ingresada

```js
function isValidDate (value) {
  var valid = false,
      info,
      real;
  
  // Validar formato
  if (/^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/]\d{4}$/.test(value)) {
    
    // Validar fecha
    info = value.split(/\//);
    real = (new Date(info[2], info[1] - 1, info[0])).toISOString().substr(0,10).split('-');
    if (info[0] === real[2] && info[1] === real[1] && info[2] === real[0]) {
      valid = true;
    }
  }
  return valid;
}

$('#enviar').on('click', function () { 
  console.log(isValidDate($('.input-date').val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-date" />
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```